# Duvida com estilização em next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Tenho esse objeto de estilização:
const imageStyle ={
width:  '33vw',
height: 'auto',
}

porem nessecito de uma media querie, como crio querys nessa forma de estilzação style-object

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.